# TypeError: must be real number, not LpAffineExpression, Optimization with PuLP

Tags: python, optimization, distance, pulp

I have the following code:

First I define the minkowski distance. It is the distance between two vectors. x represents vector 1, y represent vector 2, w represents weights of all criteria, p_value represents the p of the minkowski distance.

```
def p_root(value, root):
root_value = 1 / float(root)
return float(round(Decimal(value) **
             Decimal(root_value), 3))

def minkowski_distance(x, y, w, p_value):
# pass the p_root function to calculate
# all the value of vector parallelly
return (p_root(sum(pow(c*(abs(a - b)), p_value)
                   for a, b, c in zip(x, y, w)), p_value))
```

Then I use PuLP for optimization.

```
prob = LpProblem("Sorting Problem", LpMinimize)
w1 = LpVariable("Weight_1", 0, cat="Continuous")
w2 = LpVariable("Weight_2", 0, cat="Continuous")
w3 = LpVariable("Weight_3", 0, cat="Continuous")
w4 = LpVariable("Weight_4", 0, cat="Continuous")

epsilon1=LpVariable("Classification_Error_1",0, cat="Continuous")
epsilon2=LpVariable("Classification_Error_2",0, cat="Continuous")
epsilon3=LpVariable("Classification_Error_3",0, cat="Continuous")
epsilon4=LpVariable("Classification_Error_4",0, cat="Continuous")
.
.
.
```

Here, epsilon values represent the classification error, and goal is to minimize them.

```
prob += (
    epsilon1+epsilon2+epsilon3+epsilon4+epsilon5+epsilon6+epsilon7+epsilon8+epsilon9+epsilon10+epsilon11+epsilon12,
    "Sum_of_Classification_Errors",
)
```

This makes the sum of the criterion weights equal to one.

```
prob+= w1+w2+w3+w4 == 1
```

Here, I put the weight values in a list to utilize in the minkowski function.

```
w=[w1,w2,w3,w4]
```

Classification error occurs when an alternative is assigned to a further centroid than the one it actually is closer to. Here, we represent it.

```
prob+= minkowski_distance(train_vector[0],centroid_vector[0],w,1) - epsilon1<=minkowski_distance(train_vector[0],centroid_vector[1],w,1)-r
prob+= minkowski_distance(train_vector[0],centroid_vector[0],w,1) - epsilon1<=minkowski_distance(train_vector[0],centroid_vector[2],w,1)-r
.
.
.
```

However, at this point I get the following error. TypeError: must be real number, not LpAffineExpression. I have checked other similar questions before posting this one and the problem in those questions were trying to solve nonlinear problem with PuLP(It is a linear programming solver), or confusing the meaning of a variable in linear programs. I believe here there is a different case as in minkowski distances when the distance norm is 1 or infinite, the problem is linear. I used the distance norm as 1 here, but still I got this error.

P.S: I know the code does not seem very efficient, but I got a couple of errors trying to make it more efficient and now I am trying to ensure that the code itself works before simplifying it.

Answer (score 0):

PuLP is for linear models only (see the documentation). You try to pass on a non-linear model. Obviously, that will never work. No good reason to even try.

The code presented is incomplete, so it is difficult to decipher what is exactly going on, but you can use a distance function as long as it depends on exogenous data only. I.e. the weights (decision variables) should not be part of the distance function.